# LWP::UserAgent - determining source of response code - PERL Modules

Tags: perl, perl-module

When using the LWP::UserAgent module, one makes a request to a URL and 
receives an HTTP::Response object which contains the response code 
(hopefully 200!) and a status line.

My problem is that I can't figure out how to determine whether the 
response code was returned from the webserver or from LWP::UserAgent. 
For example, I believe that if the domain name doesn't resolve or you 
simply cannot connect to the host, LWP::UserAgent reports this in the 
form a 500 code, which is indistinguisable from a 500 "Internal Server 
Error" code reported from the actual web server that's up but 
experiencing some issues.

The problem is further amplified when going through a proxy server, as
there are now three possible "sources" of an error message:

- the target webserver
- the proxy server
- the LWP::UserAgent library

How is one supposed to know if the 500 code means a) the server is up
but unhappy, b) the proxy could not connect to the server, or c)
LWP::UserAgent could not connect to the proxy?

I posted the same question here also:
http://www.justskins.com/forums/lwp-useragent-determining-source-43810.html

Comment: [Cross-posted on JustSkins](http://www.justskins.com/forums/lwp-useragent-determining-source-43810.html). While it is not against any rule to post a question to multiple sites, it is a little shabby if you don't make it clear everywhere that you have done so. You could easily cause people to continue working to help you with a problem that has already been solved elsewhere.

Comment: Oh, believe me I, would not post this if I had a clear answer.

Comment: I added a reference link pointing to the place that I also put this question.

Answer (score 2):

> Error responses that LWP generates internally will have the
>   "Client-Warning" header set to the value "Internal response". If you
>   need to differentiate these internal responses from responses that a
>   remote server actually generates, you need to test this header value.

(from [LWP::UserAgent -> REQUEST-METHODS](http://p3rl.org/LWP::UserAgent#REQUEST-METHODS))

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;

use LWP::UserAgent;
use HTTP::Request;
use IO::Socket::SSL;

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new(
   ssl_opts => {
      SSL_verify_mode => IO::Socket::SSL::SSL_VERIFY_NONE
   }
);

my $request = HTTP::Request->new(GET => "www.example.com");
my $response = $ua->request($request);

my $clientWarning = $response->header("Client-Warning");
if(defined $clientWarning and length($clientWarning) != 0) {
    if($clientWarning =~ /Internal response/) {
       print "$server UNAVAILABLE";
    }
 } else {
   print "server AVAILABLE";
 }
```

Comment: `defined` and `eq` are enough.